# DIV styling such that contained IFRAME doesn't need to scroll

Tags: html, css, iframe, overflow

How can I insert an `iframe` inside a `div` container such that there is never a scrollbar for the embedded `iframe` content (the embedded content is never very wide, but often high enough to cause a vertical scrollbar to appear).

In other words, given

```
<div class="embedded">
    <iframe class="embedded" src="http://xxx.yyy.zzz/content.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

how can I define

```
div.embedded { }
iframe.embedded { }
```

such that the embedded content is always fully visible and never uses a scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the library http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/ to keep the iFrame sized to the content.

Example: http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
/* Hide all scrollbars for the iframe */
iframe.embedded { overflow: hidden; }

/* Hide all scrollbars for the div, but display the vertical scrollbar if content exceeds the height. */
div.embedded { overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }
```

Here's a [possibly related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566290/html-how-to-create-a-div-with-only-vertical-scroll-bars-for-long-paragraphs)

If you want the `iFrame` itself to grow taller for longer content, that involves Javascript and **was answered [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)**.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work i think - http://codepen.io/jakub_stefko/pen/EyOANY  correct me if i forgot about sth :)