# Display child Div below sibling Div of Parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have div structure as below:

```
   <App>
    <project>
        <projectTab>
        <projectBoard>
    </project>

    <project>
        <projectTab>
        <projectBoard>
    </project>

    <project>
        <projectTab>
        <projectBoard>
    </project>

    <inserTab>
</App>
```

What I want is display any active "projectBoard" below "inserTab".
If new "project" are added then by default "inserTab" is shifting down but "projectBoard" is fixed. So how can I move it as per "inserTab"

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific and provide minimal working example. SO doesn't work with screenshots

Comment: what is uncle div?

Comment: I have heard about parent div || Child div. Never experiencing that one. Kindly describe more with an example. By "uncle div" you want to refer "parent div"?

Comment: we are making relationship in programming too

Comment: LoL!!. good to know.

Comment: dhiraj raakho uncle div bani jashe

Comment: uncle js will be there comminggg sooonnn !!! Yuppo\

Comment: that was correct dude , go for uncle div , i was searching for aunty div as well

Comment: @dhiraj900 as per your screenshot, it's kind off " Unclear ". Please describe it more with a minimal working example.

Comment: @dhiraj900 its totally not clear in your screenshot, please elaborate

Comment: @dhiraj900, as per you component structure, it will be fixed always because your insertTab is after the projects and html (rendering) follows top down approach

Comment: So may be I shall use scrollview for "projectTab"

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912793/scrolling-tabs-html-and-css-only