# Scrollable table vertical only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I include my table inside a div to have `overflow: scroll`. However, it is also inserting a scrolling in horizontal. I just want the scrolling bar in vertical.

```
<div style="height: 700px !important; width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <!-- Content Here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: use `overflow-y:` property, look up CSS3. And don't double questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: How to create a DIV with only vertical scroll-bars for long paragraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566290/html-how-to-create-a-div-with-only-vertical-scroll-bars-for-long-paragraphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overflow-y` property specifies whether to clip the content, add a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

```
<div style="height: 700px !important; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <!-- Content Here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use overflow-y: scroll; or overflow-y:auto; property

The overflow-y property specifies whether to clip the content, add a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp